# Does the ASP .NET Label Add to the Weight of the ViewState Being Passed on Localization?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, label

I am currently working on a localization project for an ASP .NET application. I currently have a massive page with a multi view with about 9 tabs with each tab containing lots of data. I was just wondering, I put a lot of  tag on my ASPX page so that I could localize my text easily. I was wondering if the amount of Label has a big impact on the view state size? Or performance of the page.

I read on another text ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868587/bug-in-label-asp-viewstate-implementation)) that a single asp:Label at the minimum contains 52bytes of data. So if I have a lot of label controls it would be additional unused data being sent back and forth. I was wondering why does it even need 52 bytes of view state if it is just a label. Also, are there any other approach to doing localization in ASP .NET other than the built in feature of Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<asp:Label>` `Text` property will not be persisted in `ViewState` if does not change between Postbacks. The `ViewState` that you see generated for an `<asp:Label>` control is the data that gets generated by the label's ControlState when `SaveViewState()` is called on the Control.

Let me clarify - `ViewState` tracks changes to the page. If the text of the `<asp:Label>` is being set in the aspx markup (or code-behind) and never changes, then the size of the ViewState will not change (the `ViewState` for the Label control does not contain any data pertaining to the `Text` property). In this situation, I would be inclined to set `EnableViewState` to `false` so that no data is put into ViewState for the label at all.

I would recommend reading **[TRULY UnderStanding ViewState](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/truly-understanding-viewstate.aspx)** for more details.